# Why does this matrix form of weighted least squares not match sklearn's weight?

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-algebra

I coded up the answer to this question and it turned out not to match:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1021812/matrix-form-for-weighted-least-squares

The solutions are close, and I'm wondering if anyone knows why they don't match.

````py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np

# Benchmark

x = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]])
y = np.array([2, 9, 6, 8, 4]).reshape(-1, 1)
w = np.array([.1, .9, .5, .8, .4])

model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
model.fit(x, y, sample_weight=w)
model.coef_

# returns array([[1.90322581]])


# Solution from stackexchange

ww = np.sqrt(w).reshape(-1, 1)

wx = ww * x
wy = ww * y

xtx = x.T.dot(wx)
xty = x.T.dot(wy)

np.linalg.inv(xtx).dot(xty)

# returns array([[1.76631773]])
```
````

Comment: w matrix must be square in WLS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem in your implementation is that you mistakenly square-rooted the vector `w`. If you took a second look at the WLS formula, it is
\begin{align*}
\hat{\beta}_{\text{WLS}} = (X^\top WX)^{-1}X^\top W y, 
\end{align*}
instead of $(X^\top W^{1/2}X)^{-1}X^\top W^{1/2} y$.

Correcting your code accordingly as follows, you will match `sklearn`'s output.

```py
wx = w.reshape(-1, 1) * x 
wy = w.reshape(-1, 1) * y
xtx = x.T.dot(wx)
xty = x.T.dot(wy)
np.linalg.inv(xtx).dot(xty)
```

Comment: Possible source of confusion: the square root appears when you use OLS software to fit WLS rather than using matrices: if you regress $w^{1/2}y$ on $w^{1/2}x$ with OLS you get the WLS result.  If you write that out with matrices you see that pairs of $w^{1/2}$s multiple to $W$s.

Comment: @ThomasLumley Exactly.  If OP wanted to keep `wx` and `wy` unchanged, he then would need to change the definition of `xtx` as `xtx = wx.T.dot(wx)`.  Similarly, `xty = wx.T.dot(wy)`.